# Flexbox not working for page responsiveness

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using Flex-box to make a website responsive and yet it is not working. At the moment, everything looks normal while viewing the page in the laptop view-port, however; when I attempt to resize the browser, the background images of the three divs are the only elements that stay in place, and the navbar and everything else appears to move to the right side of the page. I've tried everything, even using media queries, and to no avail. Nothing works. What am I doing wrong here? FYI I'll be copying and pasting my whole HTML document so that someone can help me pinpoint the problem.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 600px;
}

.body-white {
  display: flex;
  height: 105px;
  margin-left: 355px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 330px;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 820px;
  flex-basis: 97%;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  height: 20px;
}

#mounts {
  flex-basis: 3%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
}

#second-ul {
  padding-left: 800px;
}

.fa {
  padding-left: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.top,
.middle,
.bottom {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

.top {
  background-image: url('img/mountains.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.middle {
  background-image: url('img/second-mountain.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bottom {
  background-image: url('img/last-mountain.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-top: 25px solid #3f5069;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #3f5069;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -10%;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#inner-box {
  background-color: #ebedf0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 20%;
  height: 35%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 100px 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#title {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  color: #3f5069;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 8px 20px;
}

.left-text {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: -12px;
  font-family: 'Kulim Park', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.right-text {
  margin-top: -135px;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Kulim Park', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.right {
  line-height: 2
}

.left {
  line-height: 2
}

@media(max-width: 1024px) {
  ul {
    padding-left: 400px;
  }
  #second-ul {
    padding-left: 370px;
  }
  .parent-white {
    margin-left: 220px;
  }
  #inner-box {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 50px 200px;
  }
  #title {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .left-text,
  .right-text {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .right-text {
    margin-top: -112px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='body'>
  <div class='top'>
    <nav>
      <img id='mounts' src='img/mountains-logo.png'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>01.HISTORY</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>02.TEAM</a></li>
      </ul>
      <i class='fa fa-bars'></i>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<nav>
  <img id='mounts' src='img/mountain-logo.jpg'>
  <ul id='second-ul'>
    <li><a href='#'>01.HISTORY</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>02.TEAM</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class='body'>
  <div class='middle'></div>
</div>
<div class='body-white'>
  <img class='white' src='img/white.jpg'>
</div>
<div class='body'>
  <div class='bottom'>
    <div id='inner-box'>
      <p id='title'>SCHEDULE</p>
      <div class='left-text'>
        <p>25 Nov 2016</p>
        <p>28 Nov 2016</p>
        <p class='left'>18 Dec 2016</p>
        <p class='left'>7 Jan 2017</p>
      </div>
      <div class='right-text'>
        <p>Vestibulum viverra</p>
        <p>Vestibulum viverra</p>
        <p class='right'>Vestibulum viverra</p>
        <p class='right'>Vestibulum viverra</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is how the page looks before resizing]
[image: After]

Comment: Change those px units to something else: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: can you share your background picture so I can use it while I diagnose whats going on for you.

Answer (score 0):

So you might not really like my answer, but to me it looks like you built a website and then tried to make it responsive after you liked the way it looked. That is not really how Responsive Web Design works. You have to start by by build each part of the web-site one by one, and make sure each part is responsive as you go. Start with a layout, make sure your layout is responsive. Then add a header, and make it responsive. Then add a Nav-Bar and make it work responsibly with everything else. Then if you have a problem come back here and post it, and devs will be able to help you better once you have narrowed down to the issue you are wanting to resolve. What you have now is kind of a somewhat modern looking static webpage that will only render on pc. To help you I would have to remove and re-add each HTML element with different CSS and that would just be building the site for you.

Answer (score 0):

1337 afterlife's answer suggests a conceptual solution, the design should be pulled together with responsive design in mind.

The right html & CSS mechanisms should be implemented for the right purposes, in UI design this is vital and often the greatest challenge, as HTML standards are ever changing allowing for better, more feature rich.

In your implementation the  tag has an  and a  child, which are stacked on top of each other, with a flex display property. This is not the purpose of the flex layout, and not the most semantic way to achieve this UI.

Consider using a background image or position:relative on both children.

For a quick fix, you could remove the padding media query applied to the  tag but this may cause your navigation bar to wrap on mobile devices